# Android: Volley request failed on my LAN

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a light python server runs on my laptop with this address: 192.168.1.56. I can access it from my other computers (LAN) without any problems. I receive my JSON data.

In my Android app, I use Volley library. And I want to retrieve some JSON data on my Python server, but it doesn't work: I have this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 192.168.1.56:5001/todo/api/v1.0/tasks

My code:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest("192.168.1.56:5001/todo/api/v1.0/tasks", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { ...
```

With another WAN URL it works perfectly.

Thank you guys!

Ps: I can ping my mobile from my laptop without any error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to add "http://" on the front of your URL.

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest("http://192.168.1.56:5001/todo/api/v1.0/tasks", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { ...
```